# Prettier format a json file

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint-staged

I have a unformatted `json` file that gets stored in my application with the following structure

```
src
 /forms
   /test
     - abc.json
```

I am using `husky` and `lint-staged` to make use of prettier and linting on pre-commit. The configuration resides in my `package.json` as following

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged --relative",
      "pre-push": "tsc"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts, json}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  ....
  ..
```

But for some reason the `abc.json` file never gets formatted when I push my code to github. What am I missing?

Comment: Do your .ts files get formatted? I think the glob pattern is `src/**/\*.{ts, json}` instead of `src/**/*.{ts, json}`

Comment: @Tyress yes the .ts files gets formatted

Comment: @RRP Did you at all try removing src and considering all ts and json files for formatting ? 
`**/*.{ts,json,}`

Comment: @Vipulw yep tried that as well still no luck, the .json file just doesn't get formatted

Comment: @RRP what is the parser defined in `.prettierrc`?

Comment: I am curious how to use node to not prettier a json file, namely compact a nice prettier json file to one single line.

Comment: Resolved. UglifyJS.minify(jsonCode, { parse: 'spidermonkey', expression: true });

Answer (score 3):

There's an error in your glob pattern. Patterns within curly braces should only be delimited by a comma

You have:

`"src/**/*.{ts, json}"`

Instead, remove the space in the pattern as follows:

`"src/**/*.{ts,json}"`